# Display Errors - PHP

Tags: php

I can't take off the warning errors on the website and it makes it look uglier than ever! I've changed the PHP.ini and restarted apache2 and the server.

```
error_reporting = 
display_errors = Off
```

Comment: turning errors off is like [trying to have your mother think you cleaned your bedroom](https://z58i.imgup.net/Spring-Cledf29.gif)... better have them ON, know them, learn from them, and work to remove them !

Comment: php entries can be overridden in the http.conf files. perhaps this is happening for you. Also try http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

try and include `error_reporting(0)` in your file with errors

Answer (score 0):

you can try display_error false in beginning

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```